# Javascript LinkedIn API read-only on a specific user

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I'm trying to get read-only public information from my LinkedIn profile through the javascript API. I currently have this code, which I know is incomplete:

```
<script>
    function linkedinAuthorized() {
        console.log("Linked in authorized");
    }

    function linkedinLoaded() {
        console.log("Linked in loaded");

        IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", linkedinAuthorized);

        var url = "/people/~?format=json";

        IN.API.Raw()
            .url(url)
            .method("GET")
            .result(function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key:   [my key]
    onLoad:    linkedinLoaded
</script>
```

I am able to load the linked in successfully, but when perform the IN.API.Raw call I get:

[image]

which I suspect is because I have not logged into an account with one of those LinkedIn login buttons.

My question is if can I get read-only profile information from a specific user without going through one of those manual authorization processes?

Comment: Did you consider scraping the public profiles? i.e. without auth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might this be linked to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21260163/6341631) ?

> My question is if can I get read-only profile information from a specific user without going through one of those manual authorization processes?

The answer is **no**. [LinkedIn use OAuth 2.0](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api), even the [tool they provide](https://apigee.com/console/linkedin) can't perform the request `https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json`.

You need to get the user logged-in to perform such actions !