# Fetch LinkedIn Contacts/Connections

Tags: ios, swift, linkedin-api

How to Fetch LinkedIn Contacts in iOS ?
I read their API but in that api to fetch connections are not available any more. Is there are other alternate way to do it ?
I tried OAUTH2 but by that I can only login and get user basic info.

This is how its done in Android . [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/90d5261287882ee3fd197b115508a437)

Comment: What's the origin of the Java file you gave? Is it tested?

Comment: @Larme Yes its tested and working fine.

Answer (score 1):

As it's mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21260163/5410373) :

> LinkedIn has restricted their open API access, and this no longer works.

This question may be possible duplicate question to: [linkedin-api-get-information-about-my-all-connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970016/linkedin-api-get-information-about-my-all-connections)

Comment: But in Android it is possible. How this is duplicate question ? I'm asking if there is any alternate way.

Comment: can you please provide a link to the android code or snippets to fetch linkedin connections , i don't think this work for one plateforme and not for others .

Comment: Why did someone downvote this? Seems like good information to me. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

As stated here:

https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition

the access for connections have been removed from the public API. You can only get access if you apply to a Partner Program which requires an official review of your app.

The example code you posted for Android doesn't actually use the public API to get the connections, it uses the API to get an access token and then uses the following URL to get the connections in CSV format and shows it in a `WebView`:

https://www.linkedin.com/people/export-settings?exportNetwork=Export&outputType=microsoft_outlook

If you don't want to use a `WebView`, you could possible download the CSV output, and parse it to get the actual data.

To parse the CSV you can use a CSV library like the following:
https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser

Comment: I know they are using that `URL` to export connections in csv but I couldn't download that csv using same session.

Comment: Are you sure you're setting the oAuth token that you get from the API to the `WebView` requests? You have to add the oAuth token manually to every `URLRequest` you make through `UIWebView`.

Comment: Yes I'm setting OAuth token but still it asks again to login.